# HTTP 502 error only for cordova plugin packages in Azure Devops

Tags: npm, ionic3, azure-devops, cordova-plugins

We have a private npm feed in Azure Devops, connected upstream with the npm public registry feed.
[image]

Suddenly, this means from today, without apparently changing anything in the project dependencies and feed configuration, when we execute npm install pointing to that feed from the project's .npmrc ( as was always) , or from the build pipelines, is giving us an HTTP 502 error but only for those packages related to cordova plugins :

```
npm http request GET https://whatever.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/whatever_Framework/npm/registry/cordova-plugin-device
npm http 502 https://whatever.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/whatever_Framework/npm/registry/cordova-plugin-device
npm verb headers { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
npm verb headers   pragma: 'no-cache',
npm verb headers   'content-length': '310',
npm verb headers   'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
npm verb headers   expires: '-1',
npm verb headers   p3p: 'CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"',
npm verb headers   'x-tfs-processid': '6d54056f-814e-4ecc-be09-fc8da2fee13f',
npm verb headers   'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
npm verb headers   activityid: 'bd75fdde-c95e-43fb-b2dc-027987a8dcff, bd75fdde-c95e-43fb-b2dc-027987a8dcff',
npm verb headers   'x-tfs-session': 'bd75fdde-c95e-43fb-b2dc-027987a8dcff, bd75fdde-c95e-43fb-b2dc-027987a8dcff',
npm verb headers   'x-vss-e2eid': 'bd75fdde-c95e-43fb-b2dc-027987a8dcff',
npm verb headers   'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
npm verb headers   'x-msedge-ref': 'Ref A: E423128E5CA7484988185432137731E1 Ref B: LON21EDGE0419 Ref C: 2019-04-16T15:54:44Z',
npm verb headers   date: 'Tue, 16 Apr 2019 15:54:43 GMT' }
npm verb stack Error: BadGateway A configured upstream registry failed: {Name = npmjs, Location = https://registry.npmjs.org/, Protocol = npm, UpstreamSourceType = Public ExceptionType = System.NullReferenceException, ExceptionMessage = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}: _packaging
```

It is curious but only fails for those cordova plugins' packages, and the project has many more dependencies, that are being resolved ok ( HTTP 200 / 304 for cached dependencies)

Some examples of npm modules attached to cordova plugins that are involved in the problem are:

```
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "1.11.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "0.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "2.0.19",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-hockeyapp": "5.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.3.2",
```

If we point directly to the npm public registry ( not going through the private feed), everything works ok, no HTTP 502 errors, and the npm install process finishes ok, so seems only happens when we install the dependencies through the private feed.

Looks like a communication problem between Azure DevOps and NPM public registry but..only for Cordova plugins modules? Strange thing... has anybody suffered this weird issue recently? Thanks.

Comment: The problem was fixed after contacting Microsoft. I dunno wether was solved manually or automatically ( without intervention) but we were about 7 hours experiencing the issue.